# Logstash filter send the entire event using the HTTP filter plugin

Tags: logstash, logstash-filter

I'm using the [Logstash HTTP Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-http.html#plugins-filters-http) plugin to call an external service and enrich my JSON event.  I can call the external service and pass an individual field from the event by doing:

```
filter {
 if [A] {
    http {
      url => "http:localhost/dosomething"
      verb => "POST"
      body => { "stuff" => ["%{[A][B]}"] }
      body_format => "json"
      target_body => "[enrichment]"
    }
  }
}
```

Referencing individual fields is covered [in the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/field-references-deepdive.html).

But is there a way to send the entire event to the enrichment, rather than a specific part (`A.B`) of the event?